# Custom onpage html based on selected slider image

Tags: html, css, triggers, slider, show-hide

Apologies if I incorrectly use some terminology here, or don't know the terms to properly describe this but...

Easy Part- I would like to create a Wheel style slider, displaying three pictures, with the main "selected" one being forefront and the other two sitting scaled down, behind them but quickly and easily clickable and viewable.

Hard Part- I would like which ever picture is set in the forefront main portion of the slider wheel to have information displayed, page width, regarding that specific toggled picture and that picture only. Then when you toggle to a different slide/picture ONLY information regarding that would then be placed below the slider/toggle wheel.

I would think my starting point would be to grab some code for the toggle/slider picture wheel. Then somehow create some sort of event trigger type coding for whichever picture is highlighted, coupling that with some sort of html hide/show coding.

I attached some bad sketches to help me visual depict what I am saying.

Any insight is welcome, even if it is some keywords to help me narrow down my google searching and find some resources. [Slide & Page Layout Sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pwXEs.png)

Thanks & Cheers

Comment: Your sketch reminded me of this: https://codepen.io/panfilov/pen/GogJVy. Hope it can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're going to need some CSS and JS to make this work.

First, you're going to need your HTML layout. I have a wrapper for the entire carousel (`.container`). I have the left and right arrows as well as a second wrapper for the images.

For the text below the carousel, I have a second element (`.content`) which holds three elements, each correlating to the images. The text is only shown when `.shown` is applied to the element.

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="left">&lt;</div>
  
  <div>
    <div class="img img-left"></div>
    <div class="img img-center"></div>
    <div class="img img-right"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="right">&gt;</div>
  
</div>

<div class="content">
  <div class="text">
    Amazing Sunset
  </div>
  <div class="text shown">
    Fall Leaves
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    Misty Sunlight
  </div>
</div>
```

For CSS I choose to make the `.container` `position: relative` so that I could use `position: absolute` on the children. I have 3 classes for the images. `img-left`, `img-right` and `img-center`. These can be animated. The arrows are simply centered vertically

```
.container {
  position: relative;

  height: 85vh;
}

.img {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;

  height: 75vh;
  width: 121vh;

  max-height: 300px;
  max-width: 511px;

  top: 0; bottom: 0;
  left: 0; right: 0;
  margin: auto;

  transition: transform 0.3s, z-index 0s linear 0.15s;
}

.img:nth-of-type(1) {
  background: url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__340.jpg') center/contain no-repeat;
}

.img:nth-of-type(2) {
  background: url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/12/01/20/28/road-1072823__340.jpg') center/contain no-repeat;
}

.img:nth-of-type(3) {
  background: url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/09/09/16/05/forest-931706__340.jpg') center/contain no-repeat;
}

.img-center {
  z-index: 5;
}

.img-right {
  transform: translateX(200px) scale(0.7);
}

.img-left {
  transform: translateX(-200px) scale(0.7);
}

.left, .right {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 7;

  top: 50%;

  font-size: 48px;
  font-family: monospace;

  transform: translateY(-50%);
  user-select: none;
}

.left {
  left: 32px;
}

.right {
  right: 32px;
}

.content {
  height: 15vh;
}

.text {
  display: none;

  text-align: center;
  font-size: 32px;
}

.text.shown {
  display: block;
}
```

JavaScript is where things start to get more interesting. I created a function called `nextImage()` which takes a boolean representing the direction to switch. First, it gets the currently centered image and then based on that image gets the next and previous element siblings. In the event that the centered image happens to be the first or last element, either `next` or `pre` will be `undefined`. That is handled next. Once that is done the CSS classes are reassigned based on the direction.

```
function nextImage(forward) {
  let currentCentered = document.querySelector('.img-center'),
      next = currentCentered.nextElementSibling,
      pre = currentCentered.previousElementSibling;
  
  //pre and next may not be elements if currentCentered is the frist or last element.
  if (!next) { //Centered Element is the frist
    next = pre.previousElementSibling;
  } else if (!pre) { //Centered Element is the last
     pre = next.nextElementSibling;
  }
  
  if (forward) {    
    //Move the previously centered image to the right
    currentCentered.classList.remove('img-center');
    currentCentered.classList.add('img-right');

    //Move the previously left image to the center
    pre.classList.remove('img-left');
    pre.classList.add('img-center');

    //Move the previously right image to the left
    next.classList.remove('img-right');
    next.classList.add('img-left');
    
  } else {
  
    //Move the previously centered image to the left
    currentCentered.classList.remove('img-center');
    currentCentered.classList.add('img-left');

    //Move the previously left image to the right
    pre.classList.remove('img-left');
    pre.classList.add('img-right');

    //Move the previously right image to the center
    next.classList.remove('img-right');
    next.classList.add('img-center');
  }
  
  //Update the text
  let currentText = document.querySelector('.text.shown'),
      newText;
  
  if (forward) {
    //Get the previous element;
    newText = currentText.previousElementSibling;
    
    //If it doesn't exist get the last element
    if (!newText) {
      newText = currentText.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling;
    }
  } else {
    //Get the next element;
    newText = currentText.nextElementSibling;
    
    //If it doesn't exist get the frist element
    if (!newText) {
      newText = currentText.previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling;
    }
  }
  
  //Apply class change
  currentText.classList.remove('shown');
  newText.classList.add('shown');
}
```

Adding `onclick="nextImage(false)"` to the left arrow and `onclick="nextImage(true)"` to the right arrow now lets you navigate with them.

Since you said you'd like the pictures so be clickable I've added a second function which lets you scroll to the given image. It gets the next and previous elements and makes sure they are actual elements. Then it called the `nextImage()` function based on if `next` or `pre` is the centered image.

```
function switchImage(imgEle) {
  let next = imgEle.nextElementSibling,
      pre = imgEle.previousElementSibling;
    
  //Make sure they are actually elements  
  if (!next) {
    next = pre.previousElementSibling;
  }
  
  if (!pre) {
    pre = next.nextElementSibling;
  }
  
  if (next.classList.contains('img-center')) {
    nextImage(true);
  } else if (pre.classList.contains('img-center')) {
    nextImage(false);
  }
}
```

All you have to do now is add `onclick="switchImage(this)"` to each of your image elements.

Adding this all together you should get something like this snippet below

```js
function nextImage(forward) {
  let currentCentered = document.querySelector('.img-center'),
      next = currentCentered.nextElementSibling,
      pre = currentCentered.previousElementSibling;
  
  //pre and next may not be elements if currentCentered is the frist or last element.
  if (!next) { //Centered Element is the frist
    next = pre.previousElementSibling;
  } else if (!pre) { //Centered Element is the last
     pre = next.nextElementSibling;
  }
  
  if (forward) {    
    //Move the previously centered image to the right
    currentCentered.classList.remove('img-center');
    currentCentered.classList.add('img-right');

    //Move the previously left image to the center
    pre.classList.remove('img-left');
    pre.classList.add('img-center');

    //Move the previously right image to the left
    next.classList.remove('img-right');
    next.classList.add('img-left');
    
  } else {
  
    //Move the previously centered image to the left
    currentCentered.classList.remove('img-center');
    currentCentered.classList.add('img-left');

    //Move the previously left image to the right
    pre.classList.remove('img-left');
    pre.classList.add('img-right');

    //Move the previously right image to the center
    next.classList.remove('img-right');
    next.classList.add('img-center');
  }
  
  //Update the text
  let currentText = document.querySelector('.text.shown'),
      newText;
  
  if (forward) {
    //Get the previous element;
    newText = currentText.previousElementSibling;
    
    //If it doesn't exist get the last element
    if (!newText) {
      newText = currentText.nextElementSibling.nextElementSibling;
    }
  } else {
    //Get the next element;
    newText = currentText.nextElementSibling;
    
    //If it doesn't exist get the frist element
    if (!newText) {
      newText = currentText.previousElementSibling.previousElementSibling;
    }
  }
  
  //Apply class change
  currentText.classList.remove('shown');
  newText.classList.add('shown');
}

function switchImage(imgEle) {
  let next = imgEle.nextElementSibling,
      pre = imgEle.previousElementSibling;
    
  //Make sure they are actually elements  
  if (!next) {
    next = pre.previousElementSibling;
  }
  
  if (!pre) {
    pre = next.nextElementSibling;
  }
  
  if (next.classList.contains('img-center')) {
    nextImage(true);
  } else if (pre.classList.contains('img-center')) {
    nextImage(false);
  }
}
```

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  
  height: 85vh;
}

.img {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;

  height: 75vh;
  width: 121vh;

  max-height: 300px;
  max-width: 511px;

  top: 0; bottom: 0;
  left: 0; right: 0;
  margin: auto;
  
  transition: transform 0.3s, z-index 0s linear 0.15s;
}

.img:nth-of-type(1) {
  background: url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__340.jpg') center/contain no-repeat;
}

.img:nth-of-type(2) {
  background: url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/12/01/20/28/road-1072823__340.jpg') center/contain no-repeat;
}

.img:nth-of-type(3) {
  background: url('https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/09/09/16/05/forest-931706__340.jpg') center/contain no-repeat;
}

.img-center {
  z-index: 5;
}

.img-right {
  transform: translateX(200px) scale(0.7);
}

.img-left {
  transform: translateX(-200px) scale(0.7);
}

.left, .right {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 7;
  
  top: 50%;

  font-size: 48px;
  font-family: monospace;
  
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  user-select: none;
}

.left {
  left: 32px;
}

.right {
  right: 32px;
}

.content {
  height: 15vh;
}

.text {
  display: none;

  text-align: center;
  font-size: 32px;
}

.text.shown {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="left" onclick="nextImage(false)">&lt;</div>
  
  <div>
    <div class="img img-left" onclick="switchImage(this)"></div>
    <div class="img img-center" onclick="switchImage(this)"></div>
    <div class="img img-right" onclick="switchImage(this)"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="right" onclick="nextImage(true)">&gt;</div>
  
</div>

<div class="content">
  <div class="text">
    Amazing Sunset
  </div>
  <div class="text shown">
    Fall Leaves
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    Misty Sunlight
  </div>
</div>
```